# Converting Farenheit to Celsius and printing to the user

Tags: c

I would like to convert everything between -50 degrees and 200 degrees Celsius, in steps of 10 degrees, to Fahrenheit, and print to the user not only both values but also which one is bigger/smaller or whether they are equal. My current code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int fahr;

    for(fahr = -50; fahr < 201; fahr = fahr + 10)
    {
        double celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32);

        if(fahr == celsius)
        {
           printf("%3d = %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        }

        if(fahr > celsius)
        {
            printf("%3d > %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        }

        if(fahr < celsius)
        {
            printf("%3d < %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        }
    }
}
```

My basic thought process was that I would need to use a for statement, with a few ifs in there for lesser than, greater than and equal to. However, whenever I use the if statements celsius only comes out as one number, and farenheit doesn't jump by ten after each conversion =/ So i am kinda at a loss as to what to do.

Edit: Alright so, kinda idiodic mistake I used = instead of ==. I'm new to programming, so i'm still trying to get it through my head that = doesn't actually mean equals. Anyways, that at least fixes the farenheit not going in correct intervals, but celsius still stays at 2.2 instead of changing each time.

EDITEDIT: Well, thanks for the help, turns out I just need to learn when to use the correct data types! I changed the code to its final form in case anyone ever needs it!

Comment: `if(fahr = celsius)` Look again.

Comment: `main` is missing a return type. You need to say `int main()`.

Comment: This looks kind of pointless ase a temperature in Celsius will **always** be lower than a temperature in Fahrenheit...

Comment: @nico, They become equal at -40 and your statement is false for all F temperatures below that.

Comment: @chris: sorry, missed the part that said from -50 :)

Comment: You should consider turning on some sort of standards checking such as "Wall" or "Pedantic". See http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-wall.htm or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c.aspx

Comment: @nico Actually it turns out that I think when -40 is plugged into the equation to turn into celsius, it also equals -40.

Comment: Someone reading from the top may start trying to answer your question or pointlessly start trying to find the problem before reading that the code is in fact "corrected" - you have rendered the question useless as an exemplar of the error as a consequence.  You should I think rather leave the "corrections" to whatever answer you accept, add an answer of your own, or include the original and then the fixed code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `if(fahr = celsius)` doesn't do what you think. It *assigns* `celsius` to `fahr` and checks whether the result is non-zero.

What you meant is:

```
if (fahr == celsius)
//      ^^^^
```

This will compare the two values for equality.

---

As a completely unrelated point of accuracy, you should write the conversion like this:

```
int celsius = (5 * (fahr - 32)) / 9;
```

This will not require any expensive conversion to floating point or rounding errors on the conversion back to integer, and it will delay the division as long as possible. Note of course that your Celsius value will only be approximate to the nearest integer towards zero.

Comment: Thank you sir, completely rookie mistake. I completely forgot = is assigning a value and not saying its equal to something >.>. Now though, the celsius values aren't changing from 2.2. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1645307: because you're using integers? If you want floating-point values, you need to use floating-point data types (like `double`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: To be picky, `celsius` will be rounded towards zero, e.g. 17/9°C is truncated to 1°C, which is not the nearest integer ;-)

Comment: Welp, that explains it. Thank you again. I actually just started learning java and I was helping out a friend with c without any knowledge other than the most basic of basics of how loops worked. So its been kinda wonky xD

Comment: @Mehrwolf: Not picky at all, but very correct! I was just being lazy... amended!

Answer (score 0):

This is assignment

```
if(fahr = celsius)
```

this is comparison

```
if(fahr == celsius)
```